# Is it possible to filter Trello records that do not have labels?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

I'd like to filter so that I only see cards that are not labelled. I can see how to filter for any combination of labels except "only show me those that have no label". I think this would be very useful, but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this as yet. Although their filtering system is pretty flexible, so if you're looking for something in particular, just hitting "F" and typing in part of the search term should work.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Unfortunately what I'm looking for is exactly that.  Cards that haven't been labeled so that they can be labeled properly.  Oh well I guess it's time to hunt and peck.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can find cards without labels buy using the `-` operator. For example, if you have a label called red and a label called blue and you want to see all cards without a label, try this:

```
-label:red -label:blue
```

The result will be any card that does not have the red or blue label. Of course you will have to list *all* of your labels for this to work.

Comment: Not very tenable if you have dozens of labels.

Comment: I can make this work in the search box, but not in the filter box (which was the original question). Have you come across a way to make it work in the filter?

Comment: @AlexWhite I can't get it working from the search box but this filter string is a good work-around for me: `board:"To Do" list:"Today" is:open -label:"Maintenance Task"`

Answer (score 3):

Now, you can filter cards that do not have labels.

On the right side, click **Show Menu** > **Filter Cards** > **No Labels**.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Trello API not to filter but probably to solve your problem, if you have programming skills. It's not a complicated API to use. https://trello.com/docs/